# class_forms on the same page

Tags: django, django-forms

I have a class PostCreateView and I want to be able to recognize 2 form_class at the same page

When I have tried it said, tupple can not be called when I write like this:

```
 form_class = PostForm, CommentView
```

Views.PY

```
class PostCreateView(FormView, LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView, CommentForm):
    form_class = PostForm
    model = Post

    # category = Category.objects.all()

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        form = PostForm()
        data = Post.objects.all()
```

Models.py

```
class CommentForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Comment
        fields = ["Name", "Content"]
        widgets = {
```

I expect my 2 forms appear on the page without no issue. But only one appears and renders:

Comment: So far I never saw the Django generic views used with more than one `form_class` and I never read something about that in the docs. Where did you get the idea for this? Have you seen it being used that way somewhere?

Comment: create view is a view that displays **a** form for creating **an** object. so you cannot do this. I suggest to create simple html form and use [DRF](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/) to create you object.

Comment: @ralf, thanks for the comment. Yes, form_class is used 2.2 Django as far as I know

Comment: @AlirezaSaremi Thanks. That seems also interesting. Can I do multiple forms within this framework? Does it slow down the web page load?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A possible solution to use multiple forms in the same view are Multiforms: https://django-betterforms.readthedocs.io/en/latest/multiform.html

Comment: You are welcome. Would you mind to accept my answer

Comment: I had the same problem with which multiform had helped me overcome